# Time-bin qubit analyzed with a second Mach-Zehnder interferometer with different path-length difference?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

We are assuming that the switch is placed at the input of the first interferometer, and directs the photons having passed through the long arm of the first interferometer (phase shift of $\alpha$) through the short arm of the second one, and vice-versa (with 100 % probability). Photons passing through the long arm acquire a phase shift $\beta$ and the light is then detected with a single photon detector D.

I know that if $\Delta L_1$ = $\Delta L_2$, the intensity of the
light in front of D will be proportional to $$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cos(\alpha - \beta)$$

But I dont know what will happen qualitatively if $\Delta L_1$ is different from $\Delta L_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on how $|δ|≝|ΔL₁-ΔL₂|$ compares to the pulse length : if δ is much sorter than the pulse length, it essentially adds a dephasing term $2\pi δ/λ$ to $α-β$, where $λ$ is the wavelength. In practice, such terms are implicitly already included in $α$ and $β$. If $δ$ is much longer than the pulse length, the pulses do not interfere and your detector D sees two non overlapping pulses, each of intensity $\frac12$.

In the intermediate regime, it is more complicated, and it depends on the precise shape of the pulses. Qualitatively, one would have interference in the central part, and to two non-interfering peaks on the sides.